# PreviewView.createMeteringPointFactory() Missing in 'Camera-View Version 1.0.0-alpha15'

Tags: android

In "Camera-View Version 1.0.0-alpha14" I was using this function "public MeteringPointFactory createMeteringPointFactory(@NonNull CameraSelector cameraSelector)".

After I upgrade gradle to use "Camera-View Version 1.0.0-alpha15" this function is missing from PreviewView class.

I can't find anything about this at changelogs.

Which function I should use for same functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your code from:

```
MeteringPointFactory meteringPointFactory = previewView.createMeteringPointFactory(cameraSelector);
```

to

```
MeteringPointFactory meteringPointFactory = previewView.getMeteringPointFactory();
```